# Emacs 27.1 drag and drop file not working

Tags: emacs

I am trying to drag and drop a file to Emacs throwing below error:

```
apply: Wrong number of arguments: #[(ad--addoit-function filename) "Æ   
!Ç=ƒ\0„\0
ƒ\0ÈÉÊ#)‡" [ad-return-value ad--addoit-function filename system-type find-file-existing-other-name find-file-visit-truename nil windows-nt subst-char-in-string 47 ...] 4], 4
```

I also tried to open file with shortcut `C-x f` but still same result

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `ad-`* references in the error message, it looks like you're using an *advised* version of the source code. Try without an init file: `emacs -Q`. Do you see the problem in that case? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

(Also, when debugging or reporting a problem, evaluate the *source* code in question, instead of using the *byte-compiled* code. Error messages and backtraces will be clearer.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes this version of emacs is customized for Smallworld Magik programming development. I am not that much familiar with emacs customisations (low level). could you please let me know where do check this init file config?

Comment: Emacs manual, node [Init File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html). Bisect it by commenting out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, ... till you find the problem.